# Difference between ' and ` in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

Could you please explain what difference between a backtick (') and a single quotation mark (') in bash programming?

Comment: If the answer below is sufficient, please do feel free to [accept](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it as is the custom of the site. No point leaving it haunting the [Unanswered](https://unix.stackexchange.com/unanswered)-queue :-)

Answer (score 0):

- [Double quotes](https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_03.html) preserve the value of each character enclosed in the quotes, except for backticks, dollar sign and backslash.
- [Single quotes](https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_03.html) preserve the value of each character enclosed in the quotes including backticks, dollar sign and backslash.
- Backticks are used for [command substitution](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html). This has been deprecated by `$()` syntax.

```bash
pg@TREX:~/foo$ foo=date
pg@TREX:~/foo$ echo $foo
date
pg@TREX:~/foo$ echo `$foo`
Tue 21 Mar 2023 09:10:21 AM EET
pg@TREX:~/foo$ echo '$foo'
$foo
pg@TREX:~/foo$ echo "$foo"
date
pg@TREX:~/foo$ echo '`$foo`'
`$foo`
pg@TREX:~/foo$ echo "`$foo`"
Tue 21 Mar 2023 09:10:56 AM EET
pg@TREX:~/foo$ echo "\$foo"
$foo
pg@TREX:~/foo$ echo '\$foo'
\$foo
pg@TREX:~/foo$ echo `\$foo`
Tue 21 Mar 2023 09:12:26 AM EET
```

See:

- [Bash guide for beginners](https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/index.html)
- [Advanced Bash scripting guide](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/index.html)

Comment: As a worthy note to include, the `\`` way of substitution has been deprecated by the `$()` syntax

Comment: Thanks, @NicolasFormichella - updated the answer :-)